# How to configure VSCode to auto insert comment chars on multi line comments

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to configure VSCode so that I can write multi line comments.

In Rust comments start with `//` or `///`. If I write such a comment then it would be nice when I hit Enter that the editor auto insert `///` in the beginning of the new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no setting in VSCode to do this. It's a *Language* feature, and must be developed by the extension that gives support to the language.

I looked at two Rust extensions ([Rust](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kalitaalexey.vscode-rust) and [Rust Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=saviorisdead.RustyCode)) but none of them presents this feature. You should fill an issue on your extension's repo.

Answer (score 7):

Update from 2020: The `rust-analyzer` extension now [has support for comment continuation on pressing Enter, although it is not enabled by default.](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/comment-continuation-copy-to-next-line-on-enter-in-vs-code/45202/9?u=strohel)

As an alternative, the [Auto Comment Blocks extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kevinkyang.auto-comment-blocks) seems to provide this for multiple languages, Rust included.

Comment: Auto comment blocks seems to break the style of /** comments in JS