# Dart on VsCode: How to enable comment continuation on pressing Enter?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to configure VSCode for Dart language so that when I'm writing multi line comments `//` and I press Enter at the end of the line, the editor auto insert comments `//` in the begginning of the new line?

I checked this question about the same feature for Rust language: [How to configure VSCode to auto insert comment chars on multi line comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542259/how-to-configure-vscode-to-auto-insert-comment-chars-on-multi-line-comments). And I learnt that this feature have to be implemented for a extension.

And I checked this extension, but don't includes Dart: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kevinkyang.auto-comment-blocks

Comment: The Dart extension does it for dartdoc comments (`///`) but not for ordinary comments (`//`).  I couldn't find an existing issue about it (which surprised me), so I've filed https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3203.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you for open an issue about it!

Answer (score -1):

Following https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26694, this feature is provided by https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kevinkyang.auto-comment-blocks, though you have to enable it.

Comment: Does it work in Dart?  The question says it isn't supported in Dart.

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote in my question, this extension doesn't work with Dart files :(